# How to use barcode scanner without pressing ENTER?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, barcode, barcode-scanner

I bought a USB barcode scanner, and i'm developing my own inventory manager.

The way it is working now, it is scanning the barcode and inputing the number in a EntryBox, then I have to press a button to check in the inventory and another to check out. I want to work with 2 conditions: If I press check-in button, every code scanned adds to inventory, and if I press check-out every item is taken off the inventory.

My USB BarCode Scanner inputs the code on the entry box as if it was written on the keyboard. And it has a button on it. When I press, it writes on the box. What I was thinking of doing it, is to use the bind event "" or "" on the scanner so, it reads the code, write it on the box and input.

These are the libraries i'm using:

```
from DB_CodeReader import Bobina, session                              #This is my Database
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, exists, engine, join, update
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import date
import sys, os
from barcode import EAN13
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why not write a function that uses the `get()` method on the entry and then write whatever behavior you want based on the entry input?

Comment: How would it work? I have an add_record function that adds to the inventory. So, i would write a new function: 
``` def auto_add ( ): 
         get( something)
         add_record( )
```

Comment: Since you want 2 buttons with separate behavior I would create 2 functions. Something like `def add_inventory():` inside that function something like `value = entry.get()` and then take that `value` variable and use pandas to write that value into your data file that is storing the inventory items.

Comment: The same for the other button with the change being that you remove data instead of adding it.

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what i'm doing it. but the problem is that i have to actually press the created button in order to add or remove.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood you I thought you wanted to use buttons.  So if you were going to bind to the entry for some type of event besides pressing a button then what kind of a condition are you going to use in order to determine if the information should be written or removed?  Seems like an unsafe idea? Pressing a button linked to the desired behavior certainly seems more intrinsically safe.

Comment: You are Right, but it's not time saving. We are using a wireless barcode scanner on our products that are on shelves. If i leave the button, I will need to scan one product, go back to the computer and click to add.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work then. I just tested it with a barcode scanner at work and it does what I believe you are looking for.  I just added the `print` statement to prove it grabs the value. I used the `bind` on the `'<Return>'` in order to grab what was entered in the entry. That should be the correct event for a barcode scanner.

```
import tkinter as tk


def call_back(event):
    value = entry.get()
    if len(str(value)) > 0:
        print(value)
        
root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.bind('<Return>', call_back)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked! I'll patch the code, and give you a proper feedback after everything is working fine! Thank you!